# Finding a probability given a box of 50 fuses where 10 are bad

Tags: probability

Below is a problem I did. I believe I did it right. However, I would like somebody to check me. I am concerned about the possibility of a computational error.

Problem:

A box contains $40$ good and $10$ defective buses. If $10$ fuses are selected, what
is the probability that they will all be good.

Answer:

Let $p$ be the probability we seek.
\begin{align*}
p &= \dfrac{ { {40} \choose  {10} }  } { { {50} \choose  {10} } } \\
{ {40} \choose  {10} } &=
 \dfrac{ 40(39)(38)(37)(36)(35)(34)(33)(32)(31) } { 10(9)(8)(7)(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)} \\
{ { 50} \choose  {10} } &=
\dfrac{ 50(49)(48)(47)(46)(45)(44)(43)(42)(41) } { 10(9)(8)(7)(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)} \\
%
p &= \dfrac
 { \dfrac{ 40(39)(38)(37)(36)(35)(34)(33)(32)(31) } { 10(9)(8)(7)(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)}  }
 { \dfrac{ 50(49)(48)(47)(46)(45)(44)(43)(42)(41) } { 10(9)(8)(7)(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)} } \\
\end{align*}
Now we need to simplfiy the expression.
\begin{align*}
p &= \dfrac{ 40(39)(38)(37)(36)(35)(34)(33)(32)(31) }
   { 50(49)(48)(47)(46)(45)(44)(43)(42)(41) }  \\
%
p &= \dfrac{ 4(39)(38)(37)(36)(35)(34)(33)(32)(31) }
   {5(49)(48)(47)(46)(45)(44)(43)(42)(41) }  \\
%
p &= \dfrac{ 4(39)(38)(37)(36)(5)(34)(33)(32)(31) }
   {5(7)(48)(47)(46)(45)(44)(43)(42)(41) }  \\
%
p &= \dfrac{ 4(39)(38)(37)(36)(34)(33)(32)(31) } {7(48)(47)(46)(45)(44)(43)(42)(41) }  \\
p &= \dfrac{ 39(38)(37)(36)(34)(33)(32)(31) } {7(12)(47)(46)(45)(44)(43)(42)(41) }  \\
p &= \dfrac{ 39(38)(37)(3)(34)(33)(32)(31) } {7(47)(46)(45)(44)(43)(42)(41) }  \\
p &= \dfrac{ 13(38)(37)(3)(34)(33)(32)(31) } {7(47)(46)(15)(44)(43)(42)(41) }  \\
p &= \dfrac{ 13(19)(37)(3)(17)(33)(32)(31) } {7(47)(23)(15)(22)(43)(42)(41) }  \\
p &= \dfrac{ 13(19)(37)(3)(17)(33)(16)(31) } {7(47)(23)(15)(22)(43)(21)(41) }  \\
p &= \dfrac{ 13(19)(37)(17)(11)(16)(31) } {7(47)(23)(5)(22)(43)(7)(41) }  \\
p &= \dfrac{ 13(19)(37)(17)(11)(8)(31) } {7(47)(23)(5)(11)(43)(7)(41) }  \\
p &= \dfrac{ 13(19)(37)(17)(8)(31) } {7(47)(23)(5)(43)(7)(41) }  \\
p &= \dfrac{ 38530024 } { 466921735 }
\end{align*}

Comment: Just use a calculator. You have the correct setup. $\binom{40}{10}$ ways to select the good fuses out of 50.

Comment: [Wolfram Alphja](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=BinomialCoefficient%5B40%2C10%5D%2FBinomialCoefficient%5B50%2C10%5D) agrees with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB says that the answer is:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you saying I am wrong? Is the answer 397/4811 exact?

Comment: You are correct, as shown in my edit.